# how to refresh table in pg-admin 4?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

When i select table with view/edit data => all Rows then i try to refresh table for newly updated data in table from object tab. it seems it's not working.this works perfectly in pg-admin 3 but in pg-admin 4 it seems it's not working at all.is this an issue in pg-admin 4 or i configured something wrong when i installed i followed all the instructions in docs on how to install it on Ubuntu exactly.can someone help me on this matter or explain it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the table and choose 'refresh' from the drop down menu.
Or better, right click on the database selected and choose 'refresh' from the drop down.

Comment: I've tried both the first one it's not working , and the second one only updates the database i mean on the left side, but the opened mini window (query editor) it doesn't refresh , i have tried both. i don't know what the issue here , i'm using pg-admin 4 browser client

Comment: PostgreSQL works on Snapshot principle. The query window will never get refreshed. But why do you want to refresh the query window? Its just an editor for queries to run

Comment: when i'm testing on db sometimes i want to know if something is updated correctly , so every time i open new window , it's doable but painful sometimes , i thought there could be a solution for that

Comment: You can always select highlight the query and run it, if the changes persist it will definitely throw an existing error. But yeah, something of the sort you are looking for does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to just right-click on your table under "Tables", select "View/Edit Data" and then click on "All Rows". This refreshes the table data.

Answer (score 0):

Just click the "play" (Run query) button over the table tabs in the editor. This will make the query run again and therefore, the data will be refreshed.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se. Unfortunately, your answer doesn't really add anything to the accepted answer.